# Azure function portal: "Code + Test" section can update code, but changes does not take effect

Tags: azure, azure-functions

In Azure function and "Code + Test" section, I can edit the code and save the changes.
I can confirm from the frontend that the changes are saved.
However when I move to test the code, the log printed are based on the original code before I made any changes. The changes never took place.

It is the very simple changes such as printing a new message:
From this code:

```
context.log("my message: ", myMessage);
```

to this code:

```
context.log("Test123 my message: ", myMessage);
```

When I do `Test/Run`, the logs are still printing "my message: " instead of  "Test123 my message: "

I don't know why this is happening. It is so confusing from a user's perspective.
I think azure portal overall lacks good design and quality control.

Could anyone please offer some explanation?

Here is the code:

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";
import { workerExec } from "./worker";

const sealWorkerFunction: AzureFunction = async function (
  context: Context,
  req: HttpRequest
): Promise<void> {
  const name = req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name);
  const responseMessage = name
    ? "Hello, " + name + ". This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
    : "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the req body for a personalized response.";

  context.log(`Http function processed req for url "${req.url}"`);

  const message = req.body;
  context.log("type of message: ", typeof message);
  context.log("Test123 my message: ", message);


  context.res = {
    // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
    body: responseMessage,
  };
};

export default sealWorkerFunction;
```

Comment: which function you are using isolated or in-process?

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin  I am not sure because I never get to choose such an option. 
 My function is a Linux node JS function.  Actually this is the first time I've heard of these words.

Comment: can you share your complete function code please

Comment: In node js, are you using V3 or V4 model?

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin  We cannot edit the code in the portal using V4 right now. Therefore I am using V3 model.

Comment: can you check are you getting any warning like "Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file. To make any changes update the content in your zip file and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting." in your function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254832/discussion-between-kid-learning-c-and-ikhtesam-afrin).

Comment: check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies?tabs=linux#remote-build , it says if your function is Linux consumption then portal editing is not supported, its only available in case of premium and dedicated plan

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin  my azure function is Linux Premium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-app-portal#language-support-details), **Portal editing is not supported for Typescript based Functions**.

**In order to change any code in typescript based function, make sure you change the code locally and deploy it in your function app.**

I tried creating one Node-js Function app with HttpTrigger in Portal and it takes Javascript code by default and Typescript code is not supported in Portal editing, Refer below:-

[image]

When I change the log context in Javascript based function app, It is getting reflected like below:-

[image]

I updated my Typescript code locally with your code and deployed it in my Node-js function app like below, It gives warning regarding the Function being Read-only:-

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is the real answer that clears all my confusions. I was really digging into a dead end on this minor detail and it has become a stone in my shoe LOL